# Find top level parent of n level child using single query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a situation where i need to get the top first level category from n level child using laravel eloquent relations let me explain with an example

[image]

Now we have n level of children, so what i want is to get the top parent level parent category so i can filter out things on the basis of it let me show you the code which i am working on

```
$category_id = 1;
$items = $cart->items()->where(function ($query) use ($type, $coupon) {
        if ($type == 'product') {
            $query->whereHas('product.coupons', function ($subQuery) use ($coupon) {
                $subQuery->where('coupon_id', $coupon->id);
            });
        } else {
            $query->whereHas('product.category.coupons', function ($subQuery) use ($coupon) {
                $subQuery->where('id', $coupon->id);
            });
        }
    })->get();
```

Now in the else part i want to get the list of those items as well who's product category top level parent is $category_id

I have seen some recursive methods or relations but i want direct top level on which i can apply some condition or way to reach the top level category inside the else part of the query

Thank you :)

Comment: There is no straightforward way of doing what you want.... You need to "denormalize" your database and store the `root_id` (id of the top level parent) on each row, or you need to become an SQL magician and pull off a recursive self joining query... I would go for storing `root_id`...

Comment: You could also look into different types of data structures to build out your tree-like data, for example nested sets, which will allow you to query for things like this efficiently.

Comment: as already stated there are ways to structure data for this purpose, like nested sets or closure tables ... adjacency lists can't deal with the unknown depths efficiently